# SpamAssassin: Site Wide Bayes not working?

Tags: configuration, spamassassin

Long ago I implemented site-wide bayes filtering as per http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/SiteWideBayesSetup.

I don’t think it ever worked, and I certainly find that my spam scores are always negative, with `BAYES_00` suggesting that Bayes wasn’t used at all.

Here is what I have in my `local.cf` file:

```
bayes_path /etc/mail/spamassassin/bayes/bayes
bayes_file_mode 0777
```

When I run `sa-learn` I find instead that the tokens are stored in individual home directories.

What is the correct method to get this working?

Supplementary Question: if I can get this working, can I combine the various `bayes_tok` and other files?

Comment: Why the down vote? Can we be more constructive?

Answer (score 3):

If you get `BAYES_00` results, then Bayes is indeed working as it has classified the email as being ham. A neutral result would be `BAYES_50`. You just need to train the Bayes database properly.

If `sa-learn` creates/updates bayes files under your home directory, then it is either not reading the desired `local.cf` file, or the `bayes_path` gets overridden by a user-specific configuration file (e.g. `/root/.spamassassin/user_config`).

You could try one of the following:

- run `sa-learn` under the same user account as spamassassin is executed
- specify an explicit path to sa-learn, i.e.

  ```
  sa-learn --dbpath /etc/mail/spamassassin/bayes/bayes
  ```
- use the `-D` option to see what is really going on, i.e. which configuration files are being read, etc.

If/when you get it working you can generally **not** combine the various database files. There are at least a `bayes_toks` and a `bayes_seen` file, because one contains the tokens learned and the other has email Message-Id:s and associated training status (spam/ham). Then there can be an optional `bayes_journal` if you use deferred syncing.

Further details available in the manpage for sa-learn:
https://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.4.x/doc/sa-learn.html